# non-ambiguity of DCFG

Tags: context-free

> Show that every Deterministic context free grammar is an unambiguous context free grammar

How can I show this ? can anyone give a proof?

Comment: What are deterministic context-free grammars? Can you add a definition?

Comment: Here is the definition from Sipser. A deterministic context-free grammar is a context-free grammar
such that every valid string has a forced handle. @Yuval

Comment: Try to use this definition to show inductively that any word has a unique parse tree. Make sure that you understand what unambiguity means, both informally and formally. Intuitively, the condition of having a forced handle forced the parsing to be possible in a unique way.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?